# Which type of material should I use to fill in gaps below the trim in unfinished stairs to basement

Tags: painting, stairs, basement-refinishing

These are the stairs to the basement and the basement is somewhat finished with LVP. Not sure whether the previous owner considered this as finished stairs, definitely not to me. I am trying to clean this stairs and give a good and simple look.

Question is

1. Trim sticks out 1.5" (hollow gap below the trim) Should I fill the gaps below the trims with, drywall / plywood??
2. Suggestions on simple/good product to paint/coat stairs?

Location: Canada

[image: unfinished_stair]

[image: Full stair]

Comment: uuummmmm,  Paint it white ?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear, there is 1 inch gap from the wall below the trim, wanted to make the trim flush filling the hollow gap

Comment: 1 inch gap ?  do you mean offset, as in the trim sticks out further than the wood beneath it  ?

Comment: Yea, thanks for correcting. Trim sticks out one to one and half inch

Comment: I'm really confused about what I'm looking at. Why is the white molding _behind_ the plywood skirt up high and _overhanging_ it down low? What's the whole situation there? (I'd be yanking it all off and doing it with drywall since there's no gap for a proper skirt board.)

Comment: @isherwood same confusion goes to me, I think it was more of a DIY for the previous owner. Before I went ahead and scrap everything, I want to reach here and see what others feel about it. Should I do something like this https://imgur.com/gallery/tKZGs

Comment: My $.03 is that it just wasn't well done in the first place. The miters are not properly mated, and that whole strategy is just odd. In my house, it would come out.

Comment: can you post on image of the wider areas, like from further back?

Comment: Which bothers you more—the crappy miters, or the fact that the molding overhangs the skirt?

Comment: @Huesmann I am not how to answer your question, just want to make it look good. Something simple and less $

Comment: @JimmyFix-it added full image

Comment: @NaveenCotha sounds like the overhangs bother you more.  Looks like maybe 1/2" overhang?  Get some 1" planks or laminated board, and cut triangles (or whatever shape the stair skirt is under the molding) to fit under the molding.

Comment: Note that you're missing the railing (and probably the 36" clearance) that the code typically wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to paint the stairs, floor paint, perhaps with a traction admixture to keep them from being slippery. Still going to look like painted plywood.

If you are not going to rip out the poor trim job, might as well just paint the exposed wood and call it a day, given what a mess that appears to be. Nothing short of adding a new sheet of drywall over the whole wall is going to make that upper section look "normal" and if you are not doing that, filling the lower part feels pointless. But you could fill it with drywall or plywood (or plain wood) as you prefer. Wood will take a bit more "toe damage" than drywall, though the paint will get scuffed in either case if toes or other things knock into that area.