# Do I need to replace this eneven stair skirts to level it?

Tags: wood, basement, stairs

I am starting to work on the stairs that lead to my basement, I noticed that the right side skirt board is unevenly installed. It sticks out 1.4 inches in the beginning and then slowly packed inside, to leave only 1/2 inch at the end. Apart from removing the skirt board and re-installing it the right way with extra shims for the end, is there anything I can do to fix these?

[image]

[Related question with more photos](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/196036/which-type-of-material-should-i-use-to-fill-in-gaps-below-the-trim-in-unfinished)

Comment: That can't be 2 inches at the top unless it's built from something other than standard two-by lumber. It appears only slightly wider than the 1/2" area. Please check your measurements. Have you removed the white trim to see what's going on back there?

Comment: Sorry my bad, re-checked it is 1.4 inches in the beginning. Also I have not removed this set of trims yet as this leads to the main floor. Still finalizing the list of supplies before getting started.

Comment: If those are actually stringers, as opposed to decorative skirts, there's not much you can do. We really need to have a good understanding of how those stairs were built.

Comment: Were it my home I'd be pulling off any and all non-structural parts to see what's what and move toward a more standard arrangement. You've got some odd stuff happening there, with lots of room for improvement.

Comment: Thanks, will try to pull out non-structural things and go from there. No this is not a replacement for earlier question. I am going to work on getting it fixed and ask any follow up questions in its appropriate question.

Comment: That appears to be housed stringers. Typically the material is 1" thick. It looks like the stairs were not set true to the walls or the walls were framed not parrelel to the other side and it was not possible for the stairs to follow both walls accurately. Can't tell since the other wall is not in the picture. There is nothing to fix there, but to remove the white trim, float the wall with drywall mud (this is an oversimplification) paint and reset the trim.